# Python - change string into arguments and pass it to a function

Tags: python

I am using python with a mysql db.
I have a table in that db storing names of functions to be run.
I would like to also add a possibility to store variables in the table, retrieve them on the fly and pass them into the function. 
However when stored in the db, the arguments are strings, and I don't know how to convert them to variable names to pass to the function.

For instance lets consider the following example where the table contains:

```
module        function      arguments  (<--columns names)
indicators    scrape_web    datapoints
```

Let's say that I retrieve the data with a mysql lib and save it in a dict such as:

```
script:{'module': 'indicators',
        'function': 'scrape_web',
        'arguments': 'datapoints'}
```

I can retrieve the module and function name, and run the function without arguments like that :

```
module = __import__(script['module'])
func = getattr(module, script['function'])
func()
```

But what if i want to pass the arguments into the function so that the function run `func(datapoints)`

```
func(script['arguments'])
```

Obviously doesn't work.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to call `func('datapoints')` or `func(datapoints)` (where `datapoints` is a variable containing some data)?

Comment: What namespace is `datapoints` supposed to be found in?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat as mentionned in the question , `func(datapoints)`

Comment: @user2357112 in the namespace of the script running the function `func`

Comment: If the args are in the calling code's global namespace then you can access them by name with, eg `globals()['datapoints']`

Comment: Alternatively, you could store pickled objects in the database.  Not every object can be pickled, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming script['arguments'] returns a string which is the name of a variable.

```
func(eval(script['arguments']))
```

For multiple arguments split the string using script['arguments'].split(",")
and use eval for each element in the list.

If you want this to be as generic as possible:

```
args = script(['arguments']).split(",")
fstr = 'func('
for i in range(0,len(args)) : fstr +='eval(args['+str(i)+']),'
fstr = fstr[:-1]
#to remove the trailing comma
fstr += ')'
eval(fstr)
```

Comment: that is great thx - what if the function takes multiple arguments? For instance if `script:{'module': 'indicators',
        'function': 'scrape_web',
        'arguments': 'datapoints, 25'}` ?

Comment: Use script['arguments'].split(",") to get a list of the arguments and call eval for each argument

Comment: @jimbasquiat I updated my answer to incorporate your comment

Comment: I have been trying `func([eval(x) for x in script['arguments'].split(",")])` but i receive the error message: `missing 1 required positional argument`. Any what is the expression i should actually use?

Comment: @jimbasquiat [eval(x) for x in script['arguments'].split(",")] will return a list so it will be 1 argument. Either your function should take a list or you should pass the arguments at the respective positions. `args= script['arguments'].splti(",")` `func(eval(args[0]) , eval(args[1]) .. etc)`

Comment: This seems to mean i need to know the number of arguments in advance (which is not my case). Any Idea how can i create the statement `func(eval(args[0]) , eval(args[1]) .. etc` programatically? if i can't pass a list of arguments i don't see how i can do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139292/discussion-between-kochoba-and-jim-basquiat).